# Можно ли сделать проверку наличия файлов стилей или непосредственно переменных при сборке?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, webpack, postcss

Допустим есть два проекта, один шаблонный и включает себя много разных компонентов, а другой сборный и имеет как и свои так и из шаблонного проекта компоненты. Он собирается, и ему нужны какие то стили, что бы не копипастить из одно в другое, он если не находит нужные стили или css переменные запрашивает их из шаблонного получает и хранит у себя.

Answer (score 0):

Проверку сделать можно, но другой вопрос в производительности этого решения. Для того, чтобы проверить существование файла у скрипта уходит определенное время (особенно, если файл физически находится на другом сервере). Также может возникнуть проблема с совместимостью версий. Например, когда вы загружаете новый css-файл, а в линках самого проекта не обновилась версия файла (`styles.css?1`), то у пользователя будут по-прежнему старые css-правила.

Рекомендую все же использовать ручное копирование или автоматизировать действия на уровне деплоя проекта.

Comment: а какие будут предложения на уровне деплоя?

Comment: тогда надо писать скрипт, который в соответствии с логикой вашего приложения забирает недостающие в проекте файлы из шаблона, обновляет версии и все это уже загружает на сервер.